# tomcat service fails to start

Tags: tomcat

i have installed apache-tomcat7 and whenever i tried to stop service got error"window cannot stop service pipe line ended" and" when i tried to start service error comes up as "tomcat service on local computer started and then stopped. some service stop automatically if they are not in use by other service or program" so wat is the problem can anybody help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have the sufficient rights to start the service. Otherwise use this to set a proper one.

Comment: Also check Tomcat logs ;)